# При извлечении кадра из видео меняется его цвет (OpenCV Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Необходимо извлечь из видео кадр и добавить к нему текст. Код:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path/to/file)
    while not cap.isOpened():
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(pfth/to/file)
        cv2.waitKey(1000)
        print("Wait for the header")

    pos_frame = cap.get(1)
    k = 0
    frames = list()
while True:
    flag, frame = cap.read()
    if flag:
       texted_image = cv2.putText(img=np.copy(frame), text='test',
                                       org=(frame.shape[:2][1] - 100, frame.shape[:2][0] - 10), fontFace=1,
                                       fontScale=1,
                                       color=(0, 0, 0), thickness=1)

        plt.imshow(texted_image)
        plt.imsave(r'.\\photos\\' + str(k) + '.jpg', texted_image)
        frames.append(r'.\\photos\\' + str(k) + '.jpg')
        pos_frame = cap.get(1)
        print(str(pos_frame) + " frames")
```

Но при сохранении изображения с текстом его цвет меняется на синий. [image: измененное изображение]

[image: исходное изображение из видео]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что matplotlib использует цветовую схему RGB, а opencv BGR.

Необходимо перевернуть каналы, либо для просмотра использовать opencv.

Для того чтобы привести каналы, можно сделать так:

```
texted_image = texted_image[:, :, ::-1]
```